# How can I remove text which is produced from weight result?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I've managed to call on HealthKit to fetch the most recent weight data. However when I run it, it includes a whole load of text as follows:

```
64 kg E457AF14-36D7-4547-AFAA-EF23DDD6642D "Health" (12.0), "iPhone10,4" (12.0)metadata: {
    HKWasUserEntered = 1;
} (2018-10-12 13:12:00 +0100 - 2018-10-12 13:12:00 +0100)
```

Here is my code:

```
    func getTodaysWeight(completion: @escaping (HKQuantitySample) -> Void) {

    guard let weightSampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass) else {
        print("Body Mass Sample Type is no longer available in HealthKit")
        return
    }

    //1. Use HKQuery to load the most recent samples.
    let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date.distantPast,
                                                          end: Date(),
                                                          options: [])
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate,
                                          ascending: false)
    let limit = 1
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: weightSampleType,
                                    predicate: mostRecentPredicate,
                                    limit: limit,
                                    sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in


                                        //2. Always dispatch to the main thread when complete.
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            guard let samples = samples,
                                                let mostRecentSample = samples.first as? HKQuantitySample else {
                                                    print("getUserBodyMass sample is missing")
                                                    return
                                            }
                                            completion(mostRecentSample)
                                        }
    }
    HealthStore.execute(sampleQuery)
}



////////////////////////////////////


private func updateWeightCountLabel() {
    getTodaysWeight { (result) in
        print("\(result)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.totalWeight.text = "\(result)"
            self.totalWeight.text = String(format:"%.2f")
            print("\(result)")
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried truncating the end first of all. Obviously all of this text is still there but it's messy and not really acceptable.

I then tried to add the following code below the private func like I'd used in another ViewController to set to two decimals. Using this code below however just results in no result being shown in the UIlabel string.

```
self.totalWeight.text = String(format:"%.2f")
            print("\(result)")
```

It's my first attempt at any sort of programming, so I'm using this first app personally as an ongoing learning process, slowly adding, changing, breaking as I go along.

Comment: the type of `result` is a `HKQuantitySample`, that is more than just a number, do not parse the string but instead look up what properties that object has and use the appropriate getters / accessors.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation gives me some useful terms to look into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re printing the result from that completion handler, which is `HKQuantitySample`. This object contains several properties, so printing the whole thing will give you the output you’re currently seeing with all the information about the object. Try printing `result.quantity` for just the measurement. Take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitysample) page from Apple about that type.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I added `.quantity` to `self.totalWeight.text = "\(result)"`. 
I'll take a look at the other suggestion now in order to understand them both - I expect this way is a nice quick fix, whilst the other suggestion places the fix elsewhere in the code (which I haven't figured out yet), but once I understand them both I can apply the learns elsewhere. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick suggestion.

You could use string `offsetBy`

```
 let weight_1 = weight.substring(to:weight.index(weight.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)) // weight is the complex output you got 
 print(weight_1)
```

This prints:

```
 64 kg
```

It should work even if the person is 120kg

Comment: I've had an initial play but it keeps coming back as 'HKQuantitySample' has no member 'substring' if I use it within the `private func updateWeightCountLabel()` to amend the `result`

I've had a read and substrings as a concept seems quite simple so I don't yet understand what I'm doing wrong. Should I be calling this somewhere else?